# Need help writing a method that adds two polynomials together

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am currently working on writing a method that adds two polynomials (given by 2 text files) together. So for example:

4.0x^5 + -2.0x^3 + 2.0x + 3.0

&

8.0x^4 + 4.0x^3 + -3.0x + 9.0

would result in: 4.0x^5 + 8.0x^4 + 2.0x^3 - 1.0x + 12

Currently, my method creates a new polynomial object, but only adds the terms in which there is a degree match. So my output looks like this:

2.0x^3 - 1.0x + 12

It is missing the first two terms, because the degrees don't match up. Here is my code (important: Polynomial is initially constructed by Node poly = null; -- so the variable poly is a node that points to the front of the Linked List of the polynomial):

```
public Polynomial add(Polynomial p) {

    Polynomial answer = new Polynomial();


    for (Node firstPoly = poly; firstPoly != null; firstPoly = firstPoly.next){
        for (Node secondPoly = p.poly; secondPoly != null; secondPoly = secondPoly.next){
            if (firstPoly.term.degree == secondPoly.term.degree){

            answer = addToRear(answer, (firstPoly.term.coeff + secondPoly.term.coeff), firstPoly.term.degree, null);
                    if (answer.poly.term.coeff == 0){
                        answer.poly = null;
                    }

            }
        }
    }
    return answer;

}
```

I'm not asking anyone to solve this for me, but does anyone have any idea what I would do next to make sure the non-matching degrees get added? I've been trying to work it out on paper, but nothing is working out for various reasons. Here is the addToRear method just in case it'll be useful to you guys.

```
private Polynomial addToRear(Polynomial p, float coeff, int degree, Node next){
    if (p.poly == null){
        p.poly = new Node(coeff, degree, null);

        return p;
    }

    for (Node temp = p.poly; temp != null; temp = temp.next){
        if (temp.next == null){
            temp.next = new Node(coeff, degree, null);
            return p;
        }

    }

    return p;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to ensure that a polynomial data structure includes *all* powers, including those with zero multipliers. In other words, the polynomial `2.0x3 - 1.0x + 12` would be represented as the collection:

```
pwr    0     1     2     3
    ----  ----  ----  ----
{   12.0,  1.0,  0.0,  2.0 }
```

Unless you're talking about *large* numbers of polynomials and *massive* powers for the high-end terms, the non-sparseness of this solution should be mostly irrelevant.

As you can see, I've also changed the *order* so that the `x0` (constant) term is first in the list since, assuming your polynomials don't have negative powers, this will also ease the adding effort. This is because the matching powers will then have matching indexes in the collection.

So, to add together the two polynomials:

> `4.0x5 - 2.0x3 + 2.0x + 3.0`
> `8.0x4 + 4.0x3 - 3.0x + 9.0`

that would be akin to:

```
pwr    0     1     2     3     4     5
    ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----
  {  3.0,  2.0,  0.0, -2.0,  0.0,  4.0 }
+ {  9.0, -3.0,  0.0,  4.0,  8.0       }
----------------------------------------
= { 12.0, -1.0,  0.0,  2.0,  8.0,  4.0 }
```

which gives, as desired (ignoring zero multipliers when outputting)

> `4.0x5 + 8.0x4 + 2.0x3 - 1.0x + 12.0`

---

If, for some reason, you *must* work on sparse linked lists, then it depends on whether the terms are sorted based on the power.

If they're not, you will generally have to use an algorithm like:

```
set poly3 to empty

# Process all in poly1, including those in poly2.

foreach term1 in poly1:
  find term2 in poly2 with matching power
    if none:
      add (term1.coeff, term1.power) to poly3 
    else:
      add (term1.coeff + term2.coeff, term1.power) to poly3 

# Process all in poly2, but NOT in poly1.

foreach term2 in poly2:
  find term1 in poly1 with matching power
    if none:
      add (term2.coeff, term2.power) to poly3
```

This will first add all powers in the first polynomial, including those that have an entry in the second.

It will then add those in the second that don't have a corresponding term in the first. That way, all terms are added correctly.

---

If the terms *are* sorted, you can make it a little more efficient by processing the lists in parallel (similar to a merge algorithm), at each stage getting the term from the list with the highest unprocessed power, something like:

```
set poly3 to empty
set term1 to poly1.head
set term2 to poly2.head

# Process both until at least one runs out.

while term1 != null and term2 != null:
  if term1.power == term2.power:
    add (term1.coeff + term2.coeff, term1.power) to poly3 
    term1 = term1.next
    term2 = term2.next
  elif term1.power > term2.power:
    add (term1.coeff, term1.power) to poly3 
    term1 = term1.next
  else:
    add (term2.coeff, term2.power) to poly3 
    term2 = term2.next

# Process remaining single list, if any.

while term1 != null:
    add (term1.coeff, term1.power) to poly3 
    term1 = term1.next

while term2 != null:
    add (term2.coeff, term2.power) to poly3 
    term2 = term2.next
```

---

As a proof of concept, here's some Python code which does the sorted variant. The bulk of the code is turning a string into a "list" (actually a power-sparse array) and printing out the resultant polynomial. The meat of the solution is in the main line, starting at `poly3 = []`:

```
poly1 = '4.0x^5 - 2.0x^3 + 2.0x + 3.0'
poly2 = '8.0x^4 + 4.0x^3 + -3.0x + 9.0'

# Makes component extraction from array easier.

coeff = 0
power = 1

def baseline(s):
    # Remove spaces, normalise to all '+'.

    check = s + ' '
    result = s
    while result != check:
        check = result
        result = result.replace(' ','');
        result = result.replace('-','+-')
        result = result.replace('++','+')

    # Create array of terms.

    result = result.split('+')

    # Make each term a coefficient/power pair.

    for i in range(len(result)):
        result[i] = result[i].split('^')
        if len(result[i]) == 1 and result[i][coeff].endswith('x'):
            result[i].append('1')
        if len(result[i]) == 1 and not result[i][coeff].endswith('x'):
            result[i].append('0')
        if result[i][coeff].endswith('x'):
            result[i][coeff] = result[i][coeff][:-1]
        result[i][coeff] = float(result[i][coeff])
        result[i][power] = int(result[i][power])

    return result

def polyprint(s,p):
    print()
    print(s, p, end=':\n   ')
    if len(p) > 0:
        print(p[0][coeff],end='')
        if p[0][power] == 1:
            print('x',end='')
        elif p[0][power] > 1:
            print('x^%d' % (p[0][power]),end='')
        for i in range(1,len(p)):
            if p[i][coeff] < 0:
                print(' -',-p[i][coeff],end='')
            else:
                print(' +',p[i][coeff],end='')
            if p[i][power] == 1:
                print('x',end='')
            elif p[i][power] > 1:
                print('x^%d' % (p[i][power]),end='')
    print()

# Turn polynomials into sparse (based on powers) array.

poly1 = baseline(poly1)
poly2 = baseline(poly2)

polyprint('poly1',poly1)
polyprint('poly2',poly2)

# Add them as per sorted algorithm.

poly3 = []
idx1 = 0
idx2 = 0
while idx1 < len(poly1) and idx2 < len(poly2):
    if poly1[idx1][power] == poly2[idx2][power]:
        if poly1[idx1][coeff] != poly2[idx2][coeff]:
            poly3.append([poly1[idx1][coeff] + poly2[idx2][coeff], poly1[idx1][power]])
        idx1 += 1
        idx2 += 1
        continue

    if poly1[idx1][power] > poly2[idx2][power]:
        poly3.append([poly1[idx1][coeff], poly1[idx1][power]])
        idx1 += 1
        continue

    poly3.append([poly2[idx2][coeff], poly2[idx2][power]])
    idx2 += 1

while idx1 < len(poly1):
    poly3.append([poly1[idx1][coeff], poly1[idx1][power]])
    idx1 += 1

while idx2 < len(poly2):
    poly3.append([poly2[idx2][coeff], poly2[idx2][power]])
    idx2 += 1

polyprint('poly3',poly3)
```

Comment: This would work, but I don't have control over the test cases that will be inputted. And zero-coefficient polynomials must be stored as null. So I'd have to modify the inputs after I received them right?

Comment: @Laugh7 there's nothing to stop you converting all nulls (though I'm not sure in what context you're using null here) to zero, doing the addition, then converting all zeroes back to null. There's also nothing wrong with taking the two linked lists to be added, creating a non-sparse array-style collection with zero multipliers included, then adding those and turning it back into a linked list afterwards.

Comment: We're not allowed to convert to any kind of array, so my only option seems to be converting the nulls to zeroes, and then converting them back.

Comment: `private Polynomial addZeroes(Polynomial p){
  
  for (Node front = p.poly; front.next != null; front = front.next){
   if (front.next.term.degree != (front.term.degree + 1)){
    Node insert = new Node(0, (front.next.term.degree - 1), front.next);
    front.next = insert;
   }
  }
  
  return p;
 }`


This is the method I wrote to add the zeros, but it still doesn't solve my problem because I need a way to check for the highest degree out of both terms.

Comment: @Laugh7, given your added constraints of having to process the lists directly, I've added psuedo-code which will do what you want.

Comment: This is very logical, thank you. My only issue with what you presented, is that I am using for loops. I cannot progress through both polynomials in one iteration due to the nature of my nested for loop.

Does this mean while loops are my only option?

Comment: @Laugh7, that would be easier, yes, at least for the ordered-merge-type solution. The unordered solution will work with `for` loops because they'll be nested.

Comment: I have tried to implement your advice into my solution, and the terms are getting added, but they are getting added multiple times. The issue is with this:

'
 if none:
      add (term1.coeff, term1.power) to poly3 
    else:
      add (term1.coeff + term2.coeff, term1.power) to poly3 
`

What you have for the else statement, is my original if statement, and I cannot figure out how I would switch those two around. My nested for loops checks every single term in Poly1 to every single term in Poly2 no matter what, which is causing the repeats.

Comment: @Laugh7, if there are no repeated powers in each list and you only add **matching powers in the first pass** and **transfer powers in list 2 but not in list 1 for the second pass,** it's impossible to do duplicate adds. I suggest you ask another question with the code as you've changed it. I believe this particular question is solved as per the proof of concept I've just added.

Comment: I've updated my code and created a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849486/need-help-writing-a-method-that-adds-2-polynomials-together-v2

My only issue now is adding the non-matching degrees from polynomial 2. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Take the maximum degree of either polynomial, and set all missing terms to zero.  That is, x^2 = 0x^3 + 1x^2 + 0x^1 + 0x^0.  (As a side note, a real implementation for numeric computing would represent polynomials in nested form, to minimize the loss of precision from adding after multiplication.)

Comment: This would work for these 2 test cases, but what if there was more than two non-matching degrees in each polynomial? This would only account for one, and since I set all missing terms to zero, I wouldn't be able to get them back.

Comment: If the terms are missing, what’s there to get back?   The representations x^2 + 1 and 0x^4 + 0x^3 + 1x^2 + 0x^1 + 1x^0 are completely equivalent.  They work for any number of missing degrees.

Comment: Since this is for an assignment, the instructions state the zero-coefficients must be null, and therefore not represented in the output.

Comment: You can either remove them, or skip them when you add.  In that case, though, you will need a way to detect -x + x anyway.

Comment: There will be no repeating degrees in the test cases.