# Need help writing a method that adds 2 polynomials together (v2)

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Background: 
I am currently working on writing a method that adds two polynomials (given by 2 text files) together. So for example:

4.0x^5 + -2.0x^3 + 2.0x + 3.0

&

8.0x^4 + 4.0x^3 + -3.0x + 9.0

would result in: 4.0x^5 + 8.0x^4 + 2.0x^3 - 1.0x + 12

Currently, my output only produces: 8.0 x^4 + 4.0x^5 + 2.0x^3 - 1.0x + 12 -- this is because of the order of my for loops which you can see below. I need the terms to be in order.

```
Polynomial answer = new Polynomial();


    //p = addZeroes(p);



    for (Node firstPoly = poly; firstPoly != null; firstPoly = firstPoly.next){
        boolean polyAdded = false;
        for (Node secondPoly = p.poly; secondPoly != null; secondPoly = secondPoly.next){

            if (firstPoly.term.degree == secondPoly.term.degree){

            answer = addToRear(answer, (firstPoly.term.coeff + secondPoly.term.coeff), firstPoly.term.degree, null);
                    if (answer.poly.term.coeff == 0){
                        answer.poly = null;
                    }
                    polyAdded = true;


            }


        }
        if (polyAdded == false){
        answer = addToRear(answer, firstPoly.term.coeff, firstPoly.term.degree, null);
        if (answer.poly.term.coeff == 0){
            answer.poly = null;
        }
        }

    }

    for (Node secondPoly = p.poly; secondPoly != null; secondPoly = secondPoly.next){
        boolean match = false;
        for (Node answerPoly = answer.poly; answerPoly != null; answerPoly = answerPoly.next){
            if (secondPoly.term.degree == answerPoly.term.degree){
                match = true;
                break;
            }


        }
        if (match == false){
        answer = addToRear(answer, secondPoly.term.coeff, secondPoly.term.degree, null);
        }
    }



    return answer;

    //alt + shift + r



}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either merge sort like method, or hash / membership lookup.

merge sort like should look like

```
Node firstPoly = poly;
Node secondPoly = p.poly;

while (firstPoly != null && secondPoly != null) {
    if (firstPoly.term.degree == secondPoly.term.degree) {
        firstPoly.term.coeff += secondPoly.term.coeff;

        /* move both of them. */
        firstPoly = firstPoly.next;
        secondPoly = secondPoly.next;
    }   
    else if (firstPoly.term.degree > secondPoly.term.degree) {
        /* move the firstPoly */
        firstPoly = firstPoly.next;
    }   
    else /* if (firstPoly.term.degree < secondPoly.term.degree) */ {
        /* add secondPoly before firstPoly, and move the secondPoly */

        addBefore(firstPoly, secondPoly);
        secondPoly = secondPoly.next;
    }   
}   

/* flush secondPoly */
while (secondPoly != null) {
    addRear(secondPoly);
    secondPoly = secondPoly.next;
}
```

If you like lookup based method.

```
/* This returns a node with given degree. */
Node lookup(int degree);
/* Adds a new term. */
void addTerm(int degree, int coeff);

for (secondPoly = p.poly; secondPoly != null; secondPoly = secondPoly.next) {
    Node node = lookup(secondPoly.term.degree);
    if (node != null)
        node.coeff += secondPoly.term.coeff;
    else
        addTerm(secondPoly.term.degree, secondPoly.term.coeff);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your while loop conditions. The way it is stated, you're saying while firstPoly == true && secondPoly = true;

Comment: It was meant to be `(firstPoly != null && secondPoly != null)`.

Comment: I see, but is there anyway this can be done with my current structure of the for loops?

Comment: Nested loop is not going to work. Alternative is to use lookup method. I updated the answer.

Comment: My solution now successfully adds every polynomial! But..now any term added from the second polynomial is out of order.

Comment: You'll have to find places in the first polynomial before adding terms from the second polynomial. That's why I suggested a variation of merge sort because it takes care of order automatically. Or you can just sort it based on degrees after adding all the terms from the second polynomial.

Comment: Yes, I want to sort it. But what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Using lambda expression, `Collections.sort(poly, (Node a, Node b) -> a.term.degree - b.term.degree)`. Or, `Collections.sort(poly, new Comparator<Node>() { public int compare(Node a, Node b) { return a.term.degree - b.term.degree) }})`. In older style, `Node` class should implement `compareTo()` method. Then, `Collections.sort(poly)` should do it.

Comment: I just wrote this method to sort it, and it works!

`private Polynomial sortByDegree(Polynomial p){
  Node prev = p.poly;
  Node current = p.poly.next;
  
  while (current != null){
   if (current.term.degree < prev.term.degree){
    int temp = current.term.degree;
    current.term.degree = prev.term.degree;
    prev.term.degree = temp;
    
    float temp2 = current.term.coeff;
    current.term.coeff = prev.term.coeff;
    prev.term.coeff = temp2;
    
    prev = p.poly;
    current = p.poly.next;
   }
   
   prev = prev.next;
   current = current.next;
  }
  
  return p;
 }`

Comment: Well. It's going to crash if it doesn't have any term (I guess it's fine in your case). The real problem is every time when you find incorrect order, you go back to the 2nd term, not to the first term, so that if input is (1,2,3,4), you'll get (2,4,3,1). You need `continue` statement at the end of `if` statement to go back to the first term which must be your intention, I believe. Not to mention that this is going to be very inefficient. Better way is just use system `sort` method with your `compare` method :)

Comment: At the end of my if statement, I have:

`prev = p.poly;
    current = p.poly.next;`

which reverts the search of the linked list back to the first 2 nodes in order to start the search from the beginning. I know this is inefficient, but can you explain why this logic doesn't work?

Also I will create a case for an empty list.

Comment: In the `if` statement `prev` and `current` are pointing the first and second terms. But when it gets out of `if`, you're moving them to next terms, which are the second and third terms. You need `continue` at the end of `if` statement block to avoid shifting.